# C# Index was outside the bounds of the array - specific help, please

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working on a small programme for booking seats on an airplane - And I keep getting this error. i want the programme to show me which seats on the plane (flysaeder) are being booking by what passenger (passagerer). Only, If I enter in more seats than I have passengers, it won't run - I need it to allow open seats (less "passagerer" than "flysaeder"). What am I doing wrong?

I'm kinda new at this, so I apologize for poor explanation.

Error occurs on "listeOverPassagerer[index] = listeOverPassagerer[i];".

```
namespace eksamenvingerne
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int flysaeder;
        int passagerer;
        Random tilfældighed = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            {
                int.TryParse(txtsaeder.Text, out flysaeder);
                int.TryParse(txtantalpassagere.Text, out passagerer);

                if (passagerer > flysaeder)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ingen frie pladser!");
                }

                else
                {
                    int[] listeOverPassagerer = Enumerable.Range(0, passagerer).ToArray();
                    int[] flypladser = new int[flysaeder];

                    for (int i = 0; i < flysaeder; i++)
                    {
                        int index = tilfældighed.Next(0, passagerer);
                        flypladser[i] = tilfældighed.Next(i, passagerer);
                        flypladser[i] = listeOverPassagerer[index];
                        listeOverPassagerer[index] = listeOverPassagerer[i];
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < flypladser.Length; i++)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add("Sæde #" + i + ": Passagernr.:" + flypladser[i]); //listboxen udskriver indholdet af hver eneste plads.

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?  The error is basically telling you that you're trying to reference an item in an array, but that item doesn't actually exist.  So there's likely an error in your logic somewhere, which isn't _entirely_ obvious to someone who didn't come up with that logic.  Which line throws the error, and what are the runtime values of the variables involved when it happens?

Comment: Oh, sorry.

The error is on "listeOverPassagerer[index] = listeOverPassagerer[i];"

I believe that the issue is that the index and array doesn't match up somehow, but I don't get it. 

(I'm actually not the brilliant at this).

Comment: Is it happening when passagerer == flyseader?

Comment: No, it happens on  "listeOverPassagerer[index] = listeOverPassagerer[i];.

Comment: One tip (not related to the question): try not to use uncommon leters in Your code, like `æ` in `tilfældighed` variable name.

Comment: Use the debugger and look at some specific variables.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic actually is causing this problem:

First you make sure that `passagerer <= flysaeder`

```
if (passagerer > flysaeder)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Ingen frie pladser!");
}
```

Then you do a for loop from 0 to `flysaeder -1`

```
for (int i = 0; i < flysaeder; i++)
```

But `flysaeder` might be larger than `passagerer` hence your access of `listeOverPassagerer[i]` will throw an exception since `listeOverPassagerer` is of length `passagerer`

Comment: This makes sense - so how can I allow less "passagerer" than "flysaeder"?

Comment: `int index = tilfældighed.Next(0, passagerer);` so  `index = 0..passagerer-1` . This doesn't look like the answer.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it's not `index` that is causing the problem, it's `i`

Comment: Yeah you're right. But that's just broken logic, not an off-by-one.

Comment: I never said it's an off-by-one